# React and Django session problem that works on Postman but not in browser

Tags: python, reactjs, django, authentication

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to implement the most simple session with React frontend and Django backend. I am aware that my methods are insecure and bad but its just a project for university and I need something that works so I should do other stuff that require sessions in my project.

This is how my backend looks for Login and SessionInfo:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    data = request.data
    try:
        user = MyUser.objects.get(username=data.get('username'), 
                                  password=data.get('password'))
        request.session['uuid'] = user.id
        request.session.modified = True
    except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("User does not exist.")
    return HttpResponse(request.session['uuid'])
```

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getsession(request):
    if request.session.has_key('uuid'):
        return HttpResponse(request.session['uuid'])
    else:
        return HttpResponse(False)
```

When I am trying to test this with Postman it always work and I get wanted session ID but when I'm trying to do same stuff with react using Axios post method it always return False. I have no clue why? It looks like Django destroys session after calling login function or it doesn't even create it.
This is how my post method looks in React:

```js
function login(){
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/evidencija/login/',{
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        }).then(
            (response) =>{
                console.info(response.data)
                getSession()
            },
            (error) =>{
                console.log(error)
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting enabled.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-vs-persistent-sessions

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not seem to be working. I tried debugging it and my login function takes data from React and it even creates a session which I tried logging but whenever I run getsession from React it returns false. It looks like its getting destroyed immediately? But it works just fine when Im doing it in postman.

Comment: @filipvista updated the answer. check your settings.py SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True

Comment: Also check this.. -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting enabled.

Comment: The issue is that the session gets deleted as soon you close the postman. so on browser you dont have the active session.

Comment: Its still not working. Its returning None when Im doing react post request

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/evidencija/getsession/ 500 (Internal Server Error) is what Im getting from Axios